# How do I use the curves tool on HSV values in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

When I click the "Channel" dropdown in the Curves tool in GIMP, the available options are "Value", "Red", "Green", "Blue", and "Alpha". However, I do not see any way to adjust Hue, Saturation, or Value curves. How do I do this?

[image: Curves]

Comment: For Saturation and Hue, you don't, which isn't too surprising given that they have very specific constraints (gamut, and circularity for hue).

Answer (score 1):

The asked thing gives a different way to do color adjustments and weird re-colorizations. Most of us have not wanted it because there exists other ways to adjust colors and maybe also because it has not been easily available in common software like GIMP or Photoshop.

Get Krita (=freeware). It's available there and it works well.

The effect may look at first a puzzle, but one can surely learn to use it. If one wants to do a weird recoloring, it's a little easier to predict the result if the colors are discrete (=there's no color gradients), like in the next example.

The original:

[image]

A certain blue is still blue, but everything else is turned to red:

[image]

I found Krita gave a good resistance when I wanted to do a certain curve. That's because I can imagine the wanted effect easiest as a polyline which contains only straight line segments. Krita makes always a smooth curve (except when clipping at the edge) which often changes radically if one point is moved a little.

If one wants HSV curves in GIMP he can install G'MIC effect collection. It's there in section Color.
I have not tested how well it works.

**Another freebie** which has the HSV-curves is Paint.NET with Pyrochild effect collection. Pyrochild collection contains Curves+ which is an extended version of the ordinary curves effect. Curves+ has also the wanted HSV mode and even better: Drawn curves can be as well polylines as smooth ones. Here's the same effect as above with Curves+

[image]

See, how the resulting hue is shown also in the curve. It helps the adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

The native Curves tool in GIMP doesn't have that functionality. However you can install a free plugin called [G'MIC](https://gmic.eu/) which does have it. I have no affiliation with this plugin or the developers. It doesn't add functionality to GIMP's curves tool, but presents a completely different interface for working with curves. It also allows curve manipulation in several other colour spaces.

Once installed, quit and restart GIMP.

1. Open an image, and do *Filters > G'MIC-Qt*.
2. In the plugin, in the Available Filters box, expand the Colors category, scroll down a bit until you see Curves and select it
3. In the Colorspace dropdown choose HSV
4. Hit Apply
5. You will be presented with several windows. One for each curve, H,S,V and Alpha, and a preview window. Click and drag on the curves as you desire.

An example

[image]Click to see larger

6. When you have finished click on the preview Window and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then hit OK to close the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can decompose the channels through color-components-decompose, select HSV mode, so your layer will become 3 layers each represents H, S or V.
Using curve tools on that and then recompose them back together.
Unfortunately, you can't see the result in real time. There's another way that allows you to adjust while seeing the result, though a bit tricky  https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/de/layer-mode-group-hsv.html